# Phrase generator is printing the wrong output

Tags: python, loops, modulus

I am trying to create a function that goes from 1 to 50 that prints 'John' on multiples of 7, 'Hi' on multiples of 2 and 'Hi John' when a multiple is both a multiple of 3 and 5. However the output seems incorrect. The function prints 'Hi' when x = 5 when it should not be doing so.

```
def phrase_generator(x):
    if x % 7 == 0:
        print("John")
    elif x % 2 == 0: 
        print("Hi")
    elif (x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0):
        print("Hi John") 

    else: 
        pass

for number in range(1,51):
    print(phrase_generator(number))
```

Comment: it prints hi for 4 not for 5

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why I get additional values in my output? For instance, I get > 50 numbers when I do print(phrase_generator(number))?

Comment: Because you are printing twice. Change the print statements in your phrase_generator to return statements.

Comment: @RobertKearns Oh I see. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly correct. I made a few small tweaks:

1. Rather than printing in `phrase_generator`, return the desired string
2. Return empty string when `x` is not divisible by 2, 3, 5, or 7
3. Print the `number` along with the string, to make sure things are working as expected

```py
def phrase_generator(x):
    if x % 7 == 0:
        return "John"
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        return "Hi"
    elif (x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0):
        return "Hi John"
    else:
        return ""

for number in range(1,51):
    print(number, phrase_generator(number))
```